# Making mathmode obey spaces

Tags: math-mode, tex-core

I know this is kind of blasphemic thing to ask, but is there a way to make mathmode obey spaces? Preferably in Plain with XeTeX.

Comment: Changing the catcode of the space to *other* or *active* seems to have no effect. The ignoring of spaces in mathmode might be hardcoded.

Comment: @Martin: The active space is by default defined to be a space character with catcode 10. Change the definition, and all will be well. See my answer.

Comment: @lockstep: As I don't think the question or any likely answer is likely to be XeTeX related, I don't think the XeTeX tag is appropriate here – even though the OP specified XeTeX.

Comment: Thanks @Harald, I knew about the active space being defined as normal space, but after the *other* catcode didn't worked as well I just gave up on it.

Comment: @Harald: This is a close call. On the one hand, I agree that the `{xetex}` tag should be removed if it turns out that XeTeX has nothing to do with the problem at hand. On the other hand, someone versed in XeTeX (i.e., not me) should decide this -- and the `{xetex}` tag may call this person's attention to the question at hand.

Comment: @Harald: As you answered the question, you seem to be the person I was talking about. ;-)

Comment: @lockstep: Me, versed in XeTeX? The notion is absurd. I have never run XeTeX, not even once.

Comment: @Harald: I was somewhat confused. You are versed in Plain, and I defer to your assessment that the question isn't likely to be XeTeX-related. Tag removed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure:

```
{\catcode`\ =\active\global\let =\ }
\everymath{\catcode`\ =\active}
```

(The space has mathcode `"8000`, which is supposed to make it active in math mode. But this is not enough for some reason. You do need the `\everymath`.)

Comment: I should add that all the catcode changing caveats apply here. But you could use this to your advantage: With `\def\ism$#1${$#1$}` you can do `\ism $x = y$` and get your math with spaces ignored as usual.

Answer (score 2):

One can use the fact that the space has mathcode `"8000`, but TeX checks the mathcode only for category 11 or 12 characters:

```
\def\spacemath{\catcode`\ =12
  \begingroup\lccode`~=` \lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{\ }}

$\spacemath{}a b$
```

If one wants this in all math, then

```
\everymath\expandafter{\the\everymath\spacemath}
\everydisplay\expandafter{\the\everydisplay\spacemath}
```

Comment: Any idea why this doesn't work in macros? For example `\newcommand{\ff}[2]{\forall {\spacemath{} #1}, #2}`

Comment: `\spacemath` does nothing if the argument has already been tokenized.

Answer (score 0):

I actually managed to somehow accidentally make it work by:

```
\catcode`\ =13 \def {\space}
```

after which

```
$$\def\space{ } meow woof$$ % the thing between the braces is U+A0
```

much to my surprise, worked.

Comment: (dodging a bump here) Ofcourse, you'd need a font which has that U+A0 "glyph" to be present.