# How to automatically separate words in inference from semantic package?

Tags: spacing, linguistics, semantics

I'm trying to use `inference` from `semantic` package to describe static semantics of a language.

I would like to separate nonterminals in inference rules with spaces without inserting them by hand.

Is there a way to automatically separate the words `SimpleExpr_1 RelOper SimpleExpr_2` from following code with spaces, as if it was written as `SimpleExpr_1\ RelOper\ SimpleExpr_2` ?

```
\inference
  {\Gamma \vdash Expr_1 : \textsc{Integer} \quad 
   \Gamma \vdash Expr_2 : \textsc{Integer}}
  {\Gamma \vdash SimpleExpr_1 RelOper SimpleExpr_2 : \textsc{Boolean}}
```

Edit: I should add, that I tried solution presented here: [Making mathmode obey spaces](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12070/making-mathmode-obey-spaces) , but for reasons unknown to me it doesn't seem to apply to `inference`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see you are already using `\quad`, the other spacing command in math mode are:

`\,` thin space

`\:` medium space

`\;` thicker space

`\quad` thicker

`\qquad` and thicker

`\!` negative thin space

Answer (score 1):

One way is to redefine `\predicatebegin` to define spaces in math mode as not ignored. A subtle point, though, is that the tokens have already been read, so spaces already have catcode 10. This can be reverted using `\scantokens`. I thought it would be best to only scan tokens from `|-` to `:`, but this can easily be changed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{semantic}

\begingroup\catcode`\ =\active%
\gdef\mathobeyspaces{\catcode`\ =\active\let =\ }%
\endgroup

\def\predicatebegin#1|-#2:#3\predicateend
  {$#1|-\mathobeyspaces \scantokens{#2}:#3$}%

\begin{document}
\inference
  {\Gamma |-Expr_1:\textsc{Integer} \quad 
   \Gamma |-Expr_2: \textsc{Integer}}
  {\Gamma |-SimpleExpr_1 RelOper SimpleExpr_2: \textsc{Boolean}}
\end{document}
```