# multiletter names in lambda calculus

Tags: spacing

First, I am new to TeX and use it only for mathematical expressions. IMHO the most striking feature is that TeX does not respect whitespaces.

1. In lambda calculus, application is denoted by juxtaposition. In programming languages based on lambda calculus (ML, Haskell) names may be several letters long, therefore, to separate names in application, a whitespace is placed between names. I want to use function names from standard libraries of those programming languages, therefore I can not just give up multiletter names. Currently I use “\ ” in application, but it seems hackish to me and clutters the code. What is the best way to do this? Example: You can take just any functional code, like `$foldr\ f\ z\ (x:xs) =  f\ x\ (foldr\ f\ z\ xs)$`.
2. BTW, is it regular in lambda calculus to embrace multiletter names in “operatorname”?

Comment: `\operatorname{func}` will indeed add a thin space when the string is followed by another similar object, but not before an open parenthesis. Would you please add some examples to your question? And maybe some reference for us to look at.

Comment: Can you give an example of the sort of thing you would like to be able to write and the output you would like it to produce?

Comment: @egreg: I added an example.

Comment: For other readers: the most popular answer is to generate the needed code with lhs2TeX.

Answer (score 9):

The [`semantic`](https://texdoc.org/serve/semantic/0) package can be helpful here. Among other things, `semantic` provides a reserved words feature that allows you to do the following:

```
% Preamble:
\usepackage{semantic}
\reservestyle{\concretesyntax}{\mathtt}
\concretesyntax{let[let\;],in[\;in\;]}

% Later:
$\<let> x = 5 \<in> x$
```

Produces this image:

[image]

You could define `foldr`, `f`, etc the same way (possibly exchanging `\mathtt` for something else).

Beyond that, `semantic` provides ligatures which provide a way to fix the spacing of `:` and `.`. (Both should have a space after, but not before.)

```
% Preamble:
\mathlig{:}{\!:}
\mathlig{.}{.\:}

% Later:
\lambda x: nat. x + 1
```

Produces this image:

[image]

Note: These styles attempt to mimick those from John Mitchell's textbook [Foundations for Programming Languages](http://theory.stanford.edu/people/jcm/books.html). (Strangely enough, the formatting in my physical copy of his book differs from the downloadable chapter online, so keep that in mind.) In my opinion, my methods above do a much better job of reproducing his formatting than egreg's answer, which destroys spacing around `:` and removes italics on the variable names.

Comment: I've edited your post accordingly, modifying the markdown a little and embedding the images. [New user restrictions are removed at 10 reputation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/new-user).

Answer (score 8):

It's not quite clear what symbols should be followed by a space and what not.

Something like

```
\newcommand{\lname}[1]{\mathop{\kern0pt\mathit{#1}}}
```

and

```
$\lname{foldr}\lname{f}\lname{z}(x:xs) =
  \lname{f}x(\lname{foldr}\lname{f}\lname{z}xs)$
```

might give good results. In other words, put each symbol you want to be spaced as argument of \lname. One might choose a different name for it: `\?` for example. It's quite hard to think how to render such formulas automatically, without explicit markup.

A similar effect as Andrew Stacey's can be obtained in standard LaTeX: the following lines go in the preamble

```
\newenvironment{lambdac}
  {\catcode` =12 \setupspace
   \makeordinary{:}% to make the colon an ordinary symbol
   %%% possible other \makeordinary declarations
   $\mathgroup0 }
  {$}
{\catcode` =\active\gdef\setupspace{\def {\;}}}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\makeordinary}[1]{\@tempcnta=\mathcode`#1
  \@tempcntb=\@tempcnta
  \divide\@tempcntb by "1000
  \multiply\@tempcntb by "1000
  \advance\@tempcnta by -\@tempcntb
  \mathcode`#1=\@tempcnta}
\makeatother
```

In the document one can use

```
\begin{lambdac}
foldr f z (x:xs)=f x (foldr f z xs)
\end{lambdac}
```

One should put spaces only where they must appear in the output.

Note: the space has mathcode `"8000`, but this mathcode is ignored when the space has category code different from 11 or 12. The indirect definition of the active space avoids a global definition that could interfere with the `\verb` command.

Note: the `\makeordinary` macro strips off the first hexadecimal digit from a mathcode.

Result:

[image: lambda calculus]

Comment: “It's not quite clear what symbols should be followed by a space and what not.” Every lambda application corresponds to 1 space. I.e. there is a space between “foldr f z” and “(x:xs)”, unlike in the common function application. (IMHO this method yields the best visual results.)

Comment: Wish I could vote this up again!  Now I see why the mathcode bit didn't work.  What does the `\mathgroup0` do?  Also, that's an important point about necessary spaces.  My version has spaces at the start of the line which shouldn't be there!

Comment: @Andrew Saying `\mathgroup0` is equivalent to enclose the whole formula in `\mathrm`, as it chooses math family 0 that always contains upright letters. `\mathgroup` and `\fam` are synonymous.

Comment: In that case, if you put in the redeclaration of `:` then your answer becomes a superset of mine!  And with more concise code.  Could you add that in?

Comment: Just tried compiling your code (to produce a screenshot - the one thing my answer still has that yours doesn't!) and discovered a problem.  `\DeclareMathSymbol` can only be used in the preamble (`unicode-math` removes this prohibition).  So either you need to set `:` as `\mathord` for the whole document, or you need to do something more wizardry.

Answer (score 5):

I've struggled with the same thing myself, and ended up with two possible solutions; first of which is basically egreg's solution (though you could just make the functions straight to macros, ie. `\foldr`). The other one is making [math-mode obey spaces](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12070/making-mathmode-obey-spaces), but that has its own problems.

In the end, you basically won't save any typing with either of those.

To expand a little, what I've done is to define macros (these are in plain-format, latex-format would look different):

```
\def\defun#1{\mathop{\hbox{\it#1}}} % define functions as math operators,
  % so they get the spacing (note: not a "full" space, but a '\,'-space.)
\def\foldl{\defun{foldl}}
\def\foldr{\defun{foldr}}
\def\map{\defun{map}}
\def\filter{\defun{filter}}
\def\head{\defun{head}}
% etc. Silly, I know.
\def\f{\mathop f} % I don't want to remove the math italic kerning from 'f',
                  % because it has some additional space
$$ \foldr \f z (x:xs) = \f x (\foldr \f z\, xs) $$
% Note: I didn't want to remove the spacing of ':', and also, I used
% a manual spacing ('\,') to separate parameters.
\bye
```

The output looks like this:
[image]

It's a little tedious, but I think it looks good.

Please note that unlike here, the convention is to have a space before the opening parens. I am hereby humbly challenging that convention. :)

Comment: Since egreg's answer is now a superset of mine, I've deleted mine.  That might mean that you don't see my reply to your comment (I don't know).  Just in case not: I agree that `\foo{}bar` could quickly get very tedious!  Maybe in this particular case it wouldn't be too annoying as the questioner doesn't seem to use any macros in this setup.

Comment: Having no space before the opening parenthesis is unfortunately wrong typesetting in this domain, the OP has such spaces (more specifically: ICFP papers typeset with lhs2TeX will put a space before parenthesis). lhs2TeX also uses `\;` rather than `\,`, but the latter can work as well.

Comment: @Blaisorblade wait, which authority has decided on that and where can I read about it?

Comment: @Blaisorblade some more thoughts, remarks and questions: 1) are the things inside parentheses a) function application, b) function arguments, or c) tuples? [A concise explanation on the use of parentheses in general on our sister site](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/6047). And finally, to my understanding, Haskell's syntax was made to mimic mathematical notation, so depending on the answer on the question above, it would be more bracing to that idea to not have the space. It would interesting to know how much of the convention was born from the work of Ralf Hinze and Andres Loeh.

Comment: @morbusg On authority: Haskellers resists style guides (though one is https://github.com/tibbe/haskell-style-guide/blob/master/haskell-style.md), but just like Knuth inferred typography from books, it's safe to infer this rule from the agreement of 100% of papers on Haskell I've seen. I've never seen this rule stated or violated. (Almost anything else is up for debate).
Since you asked, I've just checked examples from Wadler's "The essence of functional programming" (1992)—coming from well before lhs2TeX: https://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/wadler/papers/essence/essence.ps.

Comment: @morbusg Parens can be used for tuples (not here), as in `(a, b)`. Setting that aside: Haskell function application, unlike math, never needs parentheses per se—you just set the argument as a token after the function (so the space before parens is a convention, other spaces are required by lexers). Parens simply enclose expressions to alter precedence—application has otherwise the highest precedence.
Haskell can't follow math notation here, because it encodes n-ary functions as unary curried functions.

Comment: @morbusg For instance,`f x (foldr f z xs)` is in fact parsed as `((f x) (((foldr f) z) xs))`, where I've added parens around each application `f x`. This interpretation goes back to lambda calculus (though many lambda calculus people seem to really hate the spacing I'd use); the spacing goes at least back to Miranda(TM)'s, Haskell's ancestor in many respect—examples here seem mostly modern: https://www.cs.kent.ac.uk/people/staff/dat/miranda/overview.pdf.

Comment: Last: I'm sorry so many words don't give a satisfactory answer, but please check out the links. And beware: with parens outside of function applications, wildly different conventions exist :-|.

Comment: @Blaisorblade Thank you for taking the time to answer my queries. If it's just a stylistic thing, i.e. lexically unambiguous, I'd like to leave my answer as-is just to play the devils advocate, but I'll leave a note about the convention.

Comment: Your example is indeed lexically unambiguous. Thanks for being open to argument—I liked "where can I read about it" :-)