# Adjust space between words in \mathrm

Tags: math-mode, macros, spacing, catcodes

I defined the following command:

```
\newcommand{\mymathrm}[1]{\operatorname{\mathrm{#1}}}
```

The problem is that `$\mymathrm{A B}$` gives something like `AB`, which does not typeset the space between `A` and `B`.

Is there anyway I can modify the definition of `\mymathrm` so that it would typeset the space, as if I wrote `\mymathrm{A\ B}`?

Finally, it would be better if the command automatically *halves* the space between `A` and `B`

The post [Making mathmode obey spaces](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12070/making-mathmode-obey-spaces) seems relevant, but I don't know how to change `catcode` inside of a command.

MWE (based on the answer below):

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{palatino}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\mymathrm}[1]{\operatorname{\textrm{\spaceskip.15em#1}}}
$\mymathrm{max sup}$

\renewcommand{\mymathrm}[1]{\operatorname{\mathrm{\spaceskip.15em#1}}}
$\mymathrm{max sup}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: are you sure you want `\mathrm` rather than `\textrm` ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes. I'd like to combine
1) the font of `\mathrm` (which seems to be different from that of `\textrm`);
2) the spacing of `\textrm` (want to halve it though);
3) the space added by `\operatorname`

Comment: but obeying spaces is more or less a distinguishing feature of text as opposed to math, it would be easy enough to have a version of textrm that uses the same font as mathrm (as that is the default behaviour anyway) the spac in text mode is custimisable by setting `\spaceskip`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Sounds reasonable. I'll search for a way in that direction. Thanks! Also thanks for the suggestion of `\spaceskip`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\textrm` rather than `\mathrm` so that spaces can be controlled more easily.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\mymathrm}[1]{\operatorname{\textrm{\spaceskip.15em#1}}}
\begin{document}

$\operatorname{max sup} x$

$\operatorname{\textrm{max sup}} x$

$\mymathrm{max sup} x$

\end{document}
```

---

In the example document added later the fonts are set up with the somewhat surprising choice of palatino text and computer modern math so there is a big visual discrepancy beyween `\textrm` and `\mathrm`. However you can specify the OT1 Computer modern roman to be used in `\text`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{palatino}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\mymathrm}[1]{\operatorname{\text{\fontencoding{OT1}\fontfamily{cmr}\selectfont\spaceskip.15em#1}}}
$\mymathrm{max sup}$

\renewcommand{\mymathrm}[1]{\operatorname{\mathrm{\spaceskip.15em#1}}}
$\mymathrm{max sup}$

\end{document}
```

---

However you might consider replacing `palatino` with

```
 \usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath}
```

To use a more modern palatino clone setup with matching text and math fonts.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know that the default fonts are the same across `\textrm` and `\mathrm`. I might have changed it somewhere in my code.

Comment: I use `palatino` package, and this is why I have different fonts (which is intended). Can I turn-off the font changing feature of `palatino` package inside of `\mymathrm` command? I added a MWE. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @user182849 that's why questions are always better with a test file:-) I see you added one thanks, I'll look what the package is doing and add a modified answer in a bit

Comment: are you sure you _want_ palatino text with computer modern math? (irrespective of the specifics of this operator question) @user182849

Comment: Yes. I should have written a test file:) Also yes that I want palatino text with computer modern math!

Comment: @user182849 well answer updated to give what you ask for (but I wouldn't do that)

Comment: Final thanks! It works great. I knew that people prefer `\usepackage{newpxtext, newpxmath}` over `\usepackage{palatino}`. Indeed, I also like the way it changes the thinkness of math letters, but does not like the font of it (maybe because I'm not familiar with that font), so I just use `\usepackage{palatino}`.